# How to print output in Sequence like "Hi hello....." using threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to print output like:

```
hi
hello
hi 
hello
..
..
```

infinite time using `multithreading`. I tried this but every time when I am running code then getting different out put.

this is my `code`:

```
class Abc implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
            while(true)
            {
                System.out.println("Hello");

                try
                {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                }   
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
        }
}
}

public class ThreadDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Abc obj = new Abc();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(obj);        
        t1.start();

        while(true){
            System.out.println("Hi");

            try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            }   
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Threading is inherently unpredictable. If you need a certain ordering, you'll need to synchronize the threads, which in this case would defeat the already nil point of using threads in the first place.

Comment: I'd recommend to use threads only if you want things to happen in parallel. You try to have the threads execute in an alternating scheme, effectively sequential. As an exercise in thread synchronization, that may be fine, but I wouldn't do that in production code. Rule of thumb: use threads only if you have a very good reason to do so, as getting it right needs a LOT of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, two threads are started but one prints `hi` and the other `hello` without any condition.

You could use a shared **volatile boolean** variable to determinate whether `hello` or  `hi` should be printed.
For example in `ThreadDemo` :

```
public static volatile boolean isHello;
```

Then in the thread `run()` method, specify a condition to print.

In the thread that prints Hello :

```
if (!ThreadDemo.isHello) {
  System.out.println("Hello");
  ThreadDemo.isHello = true;
}
```

and in the other  :

```
if (ThreadDemo.isHello) {
  System.out.println("Hi");
  ThreadDemo.isHello = false;
}
```